# Composer can not be install: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: symfony1, composer-php

I am a newbie at symfony1.4. I am trying to install composer in my existing project I run install command get this:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1:

```
- symfony/console v2.5.4 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.5.3 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.5.2 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.5.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.5.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.9 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.8 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.7 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.6 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.5 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.4 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.3 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.2 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.4.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.9 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.8 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.7 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.6 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.5 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.4 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.3 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.2 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.19 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.18 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.17 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.16 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.15 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.14 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.13 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.12 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.11 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.10 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/console v2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for symfony/console ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4].
```

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
  imum-stability setting
  see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion f
  or more details.

Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common
 problems.

Comment: What's your php version? The error would suggest you are using too old of a php version.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the composer message is talking about Symfony 2.3 up to 2.5, not your mentioned 1.4. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Composer, run the following command to install the Composer Asset Plugin:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```